# A commutative $R$-algebra $A$ is finitely generated as $R$-algebra iff it is finitely generated as commutative $R$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I am doing exercise III.6.15 in Alluffi's book *chapter 0*. I did not find a solution online, and I tend to make stupid mistakes when I study by myself. I'd appreciate if you have a minute to skim over my solution. The exercise is:

*Exercise.* Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Prove that a commutative $R$-algebra $A$ is finitely generated as an algebra over $R$ if and only if it is finitely generated as a commutative $R$-algebra.

Finitely generated as $R$-algebra means there is an onto morphism $R\langle S\rangle \to A$ for some finite set $S$. Finitely generated as commutative $R$-algebra means there is an onto morphism $R[S]\to A$ where $S$ is finite.

Free algebra: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra

Free commutative algebra =  polynomial ring with inclusion $R\subseteq R[S]$.

*Proof.* An $R$-algebra is a morphism of rings $\alpha: R\to A$ such that the image of $\alpha$ is contained in the center of $A$. The ring $R$ is fixed and commutative, but $A$ need not be. The algebra $\alpha: R\to A$ is called commutative iff $A$ is commutative. A morphism between algebras $\alpha: R\to A$ and $\beta: R\to B$ is a morphism of rings $f: A\to B$ such that $f\circ \alpha =\beta$. I need some constructions which are not mentioned in the text book.

1.) (Quotients of $R$-Algebras) Given an $R$-algebra $\alpha: R\to A$, let $I$ be a (two-sided) ideal of $A$ and let $\pi: A\to A/I$ be the natural quotient map. $A/I$ can be turned into an $R$-algebra by equipping it with the map $\pi\circ \alpha: R\to A/I$ (note that $\pi$ sends the center of $A$ into the center of $A/I$). The resulting $R$-algebra has the following universal property:

Given an $R$-algebra $\beta: R\to B$ and a map $f: A \to B$ of $R$-algebras which kills $I$, there is a unique morphism of $\overline f: A/I \to B$ of $R$-algebras such that $\overline f\circ \pi = f$. Indeed, the universal property of quotients rings yields a unique such morphism of rings, and it is easy to check that this morphism is a morphism under $R$.

2.) (Most efficient way to turn a non-commutative $R$-algebra into a commutative one) Let $\alpha: R\to A$ be a $R$-algebra. Let $I$ be the two-sided ideal of $A$ generated by elements of the form $xy - yx$. The quotient algebra $A/I$ is commutative, and it satisfies the following universal property: For every morphism $f: A\to B$ into a commutative $R$-algebra $B$ there is a unique morphism $\overline f: A/I \to B$ of $R$-algebras such that $\overline f\circ \pi =  f$.

Indeed, every morphism to a commutative $R$-algebra kills all elements of the form $xy-yx$, thus kills $I$ and thus factors uniquely through $A/I$ by 1.). The ideal $I$ is the *commutator ideal* of $A$.

Now I'll start with the exercise. The free $R$-algebra over a set $S$ is $R\langle S\rangle$, the free commutative $R$-algebra over a set $S$ is $R[S]$.

Fix a set $S$. The universal property of $R\langle S\rangle$ together with the inclusion $S\subseteq R[S]$ yields an onto morphism $\pi: R\langle S\rangle \to R[S]$ of $R$-algebras. So clearly, if there is an onto morphism $R[S]\to A$ for some finite set $S$, then there is an onto morphism $R\langle S\rangle \to A$. This shows that if $A$ is finitely generated as a commutative $R$-algebra, then it is finitely generated as an $R$-algebra.

The other direction is harder. Let $I$ be the commutator ideal of $R\langle S\rangle$. I want to show that $\pi: R\langle S\rangle \to R[S]$ satisfies the universal property of $R\langle S\rangle \to R\langle S\rangle/I$, i.e. that $\pi: R\langle S\rangle \to R[S]$ is the most efficient way to turn $R\langle S\rangle$ into a commutative $R$-algebra. Let $t: R\langle S\rangle \to T$ be a morphism into a commutative $R$-algebra $T$. $t$ is uniquely determined by the choice of elements $t(s) \in B$ for $s\in S$. The same choice of elements determines a map $\overline t: R[S]\to B$, since $B$ is commutative. By construction of $\pi$, $\pi\circ \overline t(s) = t(s)$ for all $s\in S$. By the uniqueness clause in the universal property of $R \langle S\rangle$ we have that $\pi\circ \overline t = t$. So $t$ factors as claimed. Uniqueness follows from the fact that $\pi$ is onto (and thus epic).

Finish the proof: Suppose there is a onto morphism $R\langle S\rangle \to A$ with $S$ finite. That is $A$ is finitely generated as a $R$-algebra. Since $A$ is commutative, this morphism factors through $R[S]$, and the result is an onto morphism $R[S]\to A$. $A$ is finitely generated as commutative $R$-algebra.